# How can I complete individual command line phrases / do partial completion with fzf?

Tags: command-line, shell, autocomplete, command-history, tab-completion

With `fzf` I can press CTRL-R to search my command history but it completes the whole command. What I'd like is to just complete the current argument, the next phrase before the next space. Can this be done?

Comment: Does this link help - [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/commandline/comments/dgd74a/fzf_autocomplete_command_line_arguments/)?

Comment: @harrymc The solution shown in that is for zsh not Fish.